# How to compare two multiple values columns in SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that contains some value like : `;1;3;7;2;`
And another column with values like : `;5;2;3;`

I need to know if at least one of the number in the second column (5,2 or 3) is contained in the first column.
Of course this is an example, I have to do it for several records.

Do you have an idea ?

Here is my code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM COMPANIES 
WHERE F_SKILLS IN F_CONVENTION
```

Comment: Storing values as csv is very bad database design

Comment: Never, ever store data as semi-colon separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble. (One value per row is the SQL way.)

Comment: As others have commented: fix your DB schema for fun and profit.

Comment: Good tips and I completely agree with you guys, but It is possible that the developer can't change the database structure.

Comment: Agreed.  I've seen much worse in legacy databases.

Comment: SQL server 2016 would make this much easier. Is 2016 an option?

Answer (score 3):

Check This.

Using below query you can find all common numbers appeared in both columns.

First Create Function "[SplitLongString]":

```
        create  FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitLongString] 
        (
            @DelimitedString VARCHAR(MAX), 
            @Delimiter VARCHAR(100)
        )
        RETURNS 
        @tblArray TABLE 
        (
            ElementID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
            Element VARCHAR(1000)
        )
        AS
        BEGIN   
            DECLARE
                @siIndex    INT,
                @siStart    INT,
                @siDelSize  INT
            SET @siDelSize  = LEN(@Delimiter)
            --loop through source string and add elements to destination table array
            WHILE LEN(@DelimitedString) > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @siIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @DelimitedString)
                IF @siIndex = 0
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @tblArray VALUES(@DelimitedString)
                    BREAK
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @tblArray VALUES(SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 1,@siIndex - 1))
                    SET @siStart = @siIndex + @siDelSize
                    SET @DelimitedString = SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, @siStart , LEN(@DelimitedString) - @siStart + 1)
                END
            END

            RETURN 
        END
```

after you can cross apply to seprate out commo or semi colon. You will get common element under column element. use these column for your further use.

```
select A.*,y.Element common_element--,X.Element 
from #COMPANIES  A 
CROSS APPLY SplitLongString(F_SKILLS,';') y
CROSS APPLY SplitLongString(F_CONVENTION,';') X 
where  x.Element=y.Element and ( X.Element!=' ' or X.Element!= null)
```

> Output :

[image]

let us know if you have any query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default function that is dbo.Split('5;2;3;',',')

if you don't have this function you can create your own

Create Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO
```

after creating function you can add Condition to your Query

```
select * from yourTableName tbl where (select * from dbo.SplitString(tbl.YourColumnWithSemicoluns,';')) in (select * from dbo.SplitString('5;2;3;',';'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a finite set of just a few numbers, you might be able to get away with something as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM companies
 WHERE (f_skills LIKE '%;1;%' AND f_convention LIKE '%;1;%')
    OR (f_skills LIKE '%;2;%' AND f_convention LIKE '%;2;%')
    OR (f_skills LIKE '%;3;%' AND f_convention LIKE '%;3;%')
    ...
```

If that doesn't work...  Well, looks like some of the other answers on the page may be bit more comprehensive...  Almost embarrassingly so.  Although, if the numbers are really just 1-9 like the question suggests, I stand by my answer.  :) I know it looks a little pitiful in comparison, but, seriously, it just might work!  If not, I'd start with the one from Mr. Bhosale.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2016, check out the string_split function.

Assuming you're not, you can create a split function as per previous answer.

If this isn't an option you can do it with a CTE, but it is likely to be inefficient if you have a large dataset.

```
create table test(col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100));
insert into test values ('a;b;c', 'c;d;e'),('a;b;c','d;e;f'), ('a;b;c', 'b;a;d')


;WITH SplitSting AS
(
    SELECT
        col1, col2, LEFT(col1,CHARINDEX(';',col1)-1) AS value
            ,RIGHT(col1,LEN(col1)-CHARINDEX(';',col1)) AS remainder
        FROM test
        WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(';',col1)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        col1, col2,LEFT(remainder,CHARINDEX(';',remainder)-1)
            ,RIGHT(remainder,LEN(remainder)-CHARINDEX(';',remainder))
        FROM SplitSting
        WHERE remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(';',remainder)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        col1, col2,remainder,null
        FROM SplitSting
        WHERE remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(';',remainder)=0
)
SELECT distinct col1, col2 FROM SplitSting
where ';'+col2+';' like '%;'+value+';%'
```